# How to add a class "active" to next <div> when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wondering if anyone can help me?

I'm trying to create a slider where if the user scrolls then it adds "active" to the next div and if they scroll backup if reverses.

Like this: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Link to the page im working on: http://bluemoontesting.co.uk/bluemoon2016/vanhan.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your page is using fullpage.js which already does that, right? What'st the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) (easy example)

[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) (real documentation)

[Get the javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) (select only scrollspy)

Bootstrap has a nice Scrollspy plugin to do just that.

**Example**

```
<!-- scrollable area -->
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<!-- The navbar - The <a> elements are used to jump to a section in the scrollable area -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
...
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    ...
</nav>

<!-- Section 1 -->
<div id="section1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this page and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
...

</body>
```

Comment: Hi Randy, thanks for your answer. I have checked this out but it's not what i want to achieve. I want to be able to change slides when the user scrolls like this http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: So you don't physically scroll between the slides. As soon as the user scrolls a little bit it adds a class to the next div.

Comment: You could use jquery's scroll function to check if they scroll down, and stop the event. If they scroll down, use a slow-scroll plugin from somewhere to actualy scroll to the next div. Use it with Bootstrap Scrollspy to get the active classes to work, and use `$('.active').next()` to select the next div to scroll to :) I'm sorry but I cant implement an example without pain myself :P

Comment: I have to mention.. I wouldn't enjoy being on sites that fix your scrolling like that too much myself.

Comment: Cheers randy! I'll have ago at doing that :)